# Передача файла на java websocket частями. Получается разный размер файла

Tags: java, websocket

При передачи картинки с клиента на сервер файл сохраняется частями и дописывается, в итоге размер файла увеличился на 30%. С Клиента файл идет байтами символьной строкой. В чем может быть проблемa?

```
public class MessageHandlerEmbasFile extends TextWebSocketHandler {

@Override
protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage 
message) throws Exception {
/*
 * Перевод загрузки в строку
 * */
String payload = message.getPayload();
byte[] bytes = message.asBytes();
logger.debug("Hello from FileHandler1 " + payload.substring(0, 
4));

/*
 * Перевірка на початок закачування файлу
 * */
if (payload.startsWith("start")) {
    logger.debug("If Start" + " " + session.getId());

    Path path = 
Files.createTempFile(Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")), 
""+new Date().getTime(),".tmp");
    logger.debug("Done 
"+path.getParent()+"//"+path.getFileName());

    session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("ok"));
}

/*
 * Перевірка на закінчення файлу.
 * Викликається метод створення
 * */
if (payload.startsWith("finish")) {
    logger.debug("If finish");

    List<String> fileList = 
findFileToWrite(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

    if (fileList.size() < 1) {session.sendMessage(new 
TextMessage("Send the file againFinish")); return;}

    String fileName = fileList.get(fileList.size() - 1);

    logger.debug("FileName to front "+fileName+" Size: 
"+Files.size(Paths.get(fileName)));
     session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(fileName+"  
"+Files.size(Paths.get(fileName))));
    session.close(CloseStatus.NORMAL);
    return;
}

List<String> fileList = 
findFileToWrite(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

if (fileList.size() < 1) {session.sendMessage(new 
TextMessage("Send the file again")); return;}

String fileName = fileList.get(fileList.size() - 1);
logger.debug(fileList.toString()+"   "+fileName);
Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), bytes, 
StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("ok"));
}

private List<String> findFileToWrite(String fileNAme) {
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.list(Paths.get(fileNAme))) {
    result = walk.filter((x) ->Files.isRegularFile(x) && 
x.toString().endsWith(".tmp"))
            .map(x -> 
x.toString()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
//            logger.debug(result.toString());
    return result;
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug("Can't " + fileNAme +"  "+e.getMessage());
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

картинка - бинарные данные,

> С Клиента файл идет байтами символьной строкой.

значит есть преобразование в base64 
а это и есть 33% на увеличение размера .....

ws может и бинарные данные передавать, а значит и не будет увеличения размера и трафика